# custom icons not loading - only default red pins

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've tried a number of ways to get my customIcons to load but currently I am only getting the red pins.... I'm not sure if I've set up the switch / array for customIcons correctly. I am transferring code from v2.

[Casadragones](http://dev.casadragones.com/where-to-buy/)

This is the link to the page. The code starts in View Source on line 510.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently you use wrong labels in `customIcons.`

change them:

```
1 to establishment
2 to store
3 to distributor
```